# API call react, req.body empty on the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post

I try to do API call from my react app to my nodejs server.

Here is the server code.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 80
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
})
app.listen(port)
```

And the react app code

```
function callServerWebhook(data) {
   fetch('http://<IP>/api', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({'username': 'foo', 'password':'bar'})
   })         
}
```

When i print the req.body, it's give me an empty object. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need both `bodyParser.json()` and [`bodyParser.urlencoded()`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) to correctly parse the data:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't change anything. My server code work when i try it with postman so i think the problem is in react code.

Comment: @CharlesRA If it works in Postman but not in fetch, then my guess is it has something to do with CORS.